# Split a large folder containing many files into a set of smaller folders

Tags: homebrew, filesystem, folders, utilities

This seems like a pretty common use case:  I have a folder containing multiple files which I'd like to split into multiple folders, where each output folder is no bigger than a given size.

In short, I'd like [dirsplit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirsplit) for Mac!  I thought I'd found it with [Folder Splitter](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23175/folder-splitter/download), but this download appears to be broken.  Perhaps there's something in homebrew, but I've not found anything so far...

Comment: I just downloaded Folder Splitter and it worked.

Comment: It gave a message about the developers needing to upgrade but, I ran it and it appears to have worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the download from MacUpdate is broken, but the download from the developer's own site works: http://www.qtsync.com/foldersplitter.php

Comment: Struggled to get Folder Splitter to work on folders containing a large number of files (~500 files, each 7Mb in size).  Eventually found Big Mean Folder Machine http://www.publicspace.net/BigMeanFolderMachine/ which worked for my use case, including successfully splitting a 20Gb folder into subfolders each containing 100 files.  Cost me €15 for the fully-functional version.